# Error in JSON Parser (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm new to android programming and am working on a simple app, which will have to perfom POST and GET operations. I have a JSON parser class which creates a http request, but I keep getting an error on 'GET'. I have spent some time now trying to debug that and I have re-written the code a couple of times (I have also found similar threads on SO, but the suggested solutions didn't work for me), but I still cannot figure out what is wrong, as I keep getting the same error.

Comment: if you send a GET request to the same URL using a browser or another program, do you get a properly formed JSON?

Comment: Have you tried it using POST method??

Comment: first of all check you link, is it giving a correct response?

Comment: I haven't tried the POST method yet, as I wanted to fix GET first... 
And yes, the url works as it should! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare Strings in Java so you need to convert:

```
if(method == "GET")
```

to:

```
if(method.equals("GET"))
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately this didn't fix the problem - I still get the same error :/

Comment: @eee how are you calling makeHttpRequest?

Comment: @eee also in your switch(status) block, if there is another common error like (404, 500 , ...), then the json string will be "" which when you try to parse it, you will get an error

Comment: Thanks, true, I didn't think about that,  I've now deleted the switch statement, and moved the contents of it in another try/catch statement. 
I've edited the OP so it now contains the call of the method.

Comment: @eee please update your makeHttpRequest to reflect your latest changes

Comment: @eee you get the same error and exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

As Pooya have said you need to use ".equals".

Moreover, to avoid some null pointer you can invert the check

`if("GET".equals(method))`